# No module named certifi

Tags: python, cron, slurm, modulenotfounderror, certifi

When executing python3 (Python 3.6.8) script on a local directory, it works well, but when running sbatch job in slurm, complains about certifi.

```
python3 -m pip install certifi

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2020.12.5)
```

After adding to the python code this:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

or this:

```
import sys
import os
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

if module_path not in sys.path:

    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

the same error occurs. It seems that certifi is installed.

```
pip show certifi

Name: certifi
Version: 2020.12.5
Summary: Python package for providing Mozilla's CA Bundle.
Home-page: https://certifiio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.com
License: MPL-2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: requests
```

The error after running python code (without having the line 'import certifi' in python code):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/test/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    from textattack.augmentation import WordNetAugmenter, EmbeddingAugmenter, EasyDataAugmenter, CharSwapAugmenter
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/textattack/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/textattack/attack_recipes/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .attack_recipe import AttackRecipe
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/textattack/attack_recipes/attack_recipe.py", line 9, in <module>
    from textattack.shared import Attack
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/textattack/shared/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/textattack/shared/utils/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .install import *
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/textattack/shared/utils/install.py", line 9, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from certifi import where
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi'
```

The error (with having the line 'import certifi' in python code):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/projecttest_LR_attack/LR_attack.py", line 17, in <module>
    import certifi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi'
```

What could be the solution to the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the same modules installed on the compute nodes as locally? You may need to check with the Slurm admins.

Comment: Thank you. The advice I got was to create a VM with all needed installations.

Answer (score 15):

If you landed here because you are having issues in the MacOS with `httpie` (or any other python-based command), try installing the python-certifi with homebrew. This should have been installed as part of dependencies, but for some reason it doesn't do that always.

```
brew install python-certifi
```

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue.  However, I also needed to do the same for `pygments`.  Seems like a temporary packaging bug in the brew formula?

Comment: I had the same problem. And like @JeremyHuiskamp mentioned, `pygments` was the next one. I noticed that `python-certifi` is also required by `ca-certificates`. I played around with it and after installing `python-certifi`, i was able to remove/install `httpie` and then `pygments` was installed as a dependency, as it should be. The whole problem started after the last Python 3 update and I'm wondering if something messed with `python-certifi` or homebrew which caused the dependency resolution to fail for `python-certifi` and then that cascaded to the other deps?

Comment: The brew package is now "certifi". `brew install certifi`. You may need to re-link it. `brew link certifi`, or `brew link --overwrite certifi`

Answer (score 3):

for anyone on MacOS and already ran `pip install certifi` and still doesn't work

Go to your `applications` folder > find your `python version` folder -> double click on the file `Install Certificates.command` inside the python folder to install the certificate.

wait for it to complete the installation

After that, you can try running your code with requests package again

Answer (score 0):

This could mean that `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` is not your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable that sbatch job in slurm has access to. You can either add it or append it during runtime:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, PApostol. But the error remains the same...

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip<Python version> install certifi` if you use Homebrew.
For example, in your stack trace, you can see `python3.6`:

```
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/certs.py", line 15, in <module>
```

In this case, the command you will run is this:

```bash
pip3.6 install certifi
```

Answer (score 0):

`brew install certifi` fixed my issue

Answer (score -5):

pip install certifi

Try this command on the CLI

Comment: OP has already shared the output of "pip show" command. If you are only looking for more info (say, output of pip install), it should be asked for via a comment on the question.