I broke pip by uninstalling all packages
For a very stupid reason I decided to uninstall all packages from pip freeze, including those installed in the OS.
When I tried to reinstall the wanted packages, I get a wall of text error ending with
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi'
The full error is simial to the one in this question but since I'm on Windows the answers don't work for me.
I tried pip install certifi but I get the same error.
I tried to uninstall and reinstall python (3.12.4) but I get the same error whenever I run a pip command.
I downloaded and executed get-pip.py to reinstall pip but I yet have the same error during execution.
Anyone has any idea how to fix my stupid decision?

Are you on MacOS? If so, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034437/no-module-named-certifi

I forgot to mention that I'm on Windows, I just updated the tags

What exactly did you install and where; what is your sys.path when the import fails and where exactly is pip installed?

If you removed the libraries in the OS, then you may need to reinstall it. If you have any disk backups, I suggest loading them... you could also transfer the files you need to a USB drive and then reinstall Windows. Alternatively, if you uninstalled Python default libraries (such as certifi) then you could install them using some Windows equivalent of Homebrew.

I managed to solve it with the help of this answer.
Basically I uninstalled the certifi package that's needed for pip to function properly and I couldn't reinstall it back since pip can't function without it.
To manually install it without using pip, I downloaded the whl certifi files directly from PyPi, extracted the files by unzipping the .whl and copied the extracted certify folder into the PythonXX\Lib\site-packages directory.
Now pip works perfectly again!
Thanks to XenonPy to guiding me in the right direction with his answer.
